# Is it possible to set up an ssh reverse tunnel using a non existent sub-domain on the remote host?

Tags: linux, apache, testing, ssh

I want to be able to test on localhost but I am integrating with an API that requires a public host. In some cases the API doesn't like ports. This is probably going to be easier to explain with examples.

What I'm doing now:

> ssh -nN -f -R myexternaldomain.com:49086:localhost:86 myid@mydomain.com

But the API doesn't like it when I tell them to ping https://myexternaldomain.com:49086

The idea of what I'd like to do:

> ssh -nN -f -R subdomain.myexternaldomain.com:localhost:86 myid@mydomain.com

The goal is that when someone hits https://subdomain.myexternaldomain.com it would forward the traffic to port 86 on my laptop. Is there any way of achieving this if the subdomain doesn't already exist and with no configuration on myexternaldomain.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh -nN -f -R subdomain.myexternaldomain.com:localhost:86 myid@mydomain.com
```

In this example, I guess you really mean this, because you have to specify a port number for the remote end of the tunnel:

```
ssh -nN -f -R subdomain.myexternaldomain.com:49086:localhost:86 myid@mydomain.com
                                             ^^^^^
```

In this example, the `ssh` server on mydomain.com is going to listen for connections on subdomain.myexternaldomain.com port 49086, and tunnel those to localhost port 86 on the local host. Being able to use a name like "subdomain.myexternaldomain.com" is just a convenience; the server has to convert it to an IP address to use it.

So no, it can't be a completely made-up name. The remote server has to be able to resolve that name into an IP address. If you don't want to add the name to DNS, you could add it to the `/etc/hosts` file on the server.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for, but it's given me some more clarity on how to think about it and since it's the only answer in six months I'm going to accept it.